# C# Winform ActiveX error while add in VFP form

Tags: c#, activex, visual-foxpro

I create one ActiveX control for PDFViewer (PdfiumViewer.dll) to use in Visual FoxPro form.

When adding to the Visual Foxpro form, I received the following error:

> first time Ole Error class not registered  ole error code 0x80040154

then

> Ole Error code 0x80070002: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Build : 846
.NetFramework :2.0

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]

Comment: register with regasm /codebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed with  RegAsm with /codebase